# Unitary evolution of the displacement operator in terms of positions and momenta

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-optics, unitarity

Consider a set of $M$ *signal* modes described by the creation operators $\mathbf a^\dagger = (a_1^\dagger,...,a_M^\dagger)$, and let $\Phi_U$ be the channel defined by the conjugation $\Phi_U(\cdot)=U(\cdot) U^\dagger$ by a unitary $U$ operator acting on the mode vector as $U \mathbf a^\dagger U^\dagger = G \mathbf a^\dagger$ for a symmetric, unitary matrix $G$ ($U\mathbf a^\dagger U^\dagger$ should be read as the component-wise application of the unitary to each mode).

One can define the displacement operator in terms of these modes as $D_{\boldsymbol\alpha}=\exp(\boldsymbol\alpha \cdot \mathbf a^\dagger - \boldsymbol\alpha^*\mathbf a)$, for a vector of complex numbers $\boldsymbol\alpha=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_M)$. Equivalently, introducing a vector of $2M$ real variables $\mathbf s$, as well as the vector $\mathbf r = (x_1, p_1,...,x_M,p_M)$ of position and momentum operator for each mode, one can define the displacement operator as $D_{\mathbf r}=\exp(i\mathbf s^T\Omega \mathbf r)$, where $\Omega$ is the symplectic form
$$\Omega = \bigoplus_{j=1}^M\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}. $$ The mode operators and the positions/momenta are related by the usual identity $a_j=(x_j+ip_j)/\sqrt 2$. With a short computation, one can verify that
$UD_{\boldsymbol\alpha}U^\dagger = D_{G\boldsymbol\alpha}.$ I would like to find a similar expression for $UD_{\mathbf s}U^\dagger$, which involves computing $U(\mathbf s^T\Omega \mathbf r)U^\dagger$, but I am a little unsure about a couple points. I write
$$U(\mathbf s^T\Omega \mathbf r)U^\dagger = \mathbf s^T U\Omega U^\dagger \cdot U\mathbf r  U^\dagger $$ since in principle $\Omega$ does not commute with $U$. Then using the identity above we can exploit the fact that
$$U a_j^\dagger U^\dagger = \sum_k G_{jk}a_k^\dagger \  \Rightarrow \ \begin{cases} \displaystyle U x_j U^\dagger=\sum_k G_{jk}x_k, \\ \displaystyle U p_j U^\dagger=\sum_k G_{jk}p_k\end{cases},$$ or more compactly $U \mathbf r U^\dagger = \tilde G \mathbf r$, where $\tilde G$ is an enlarged $2M\times M$ version of the $M\times M$ matrix $G$ built by duplicating each row. This should take care of the first part of the problem. However, I'm not sure whether I can safely write $U\Omega U^\dagger = \Omega$, as $U$ isn't defined explicitly but merely by its action on the mode operators. Does anyone have an opinion on this?

Comment: if I understand your notation correctly, $U$ doesn't act on $\Omega$ at all. You have it act on the operator only: $U({\bf s}^T\Omega {\bf r})U^\dagger=s_i \Omega_{ij} U\hat r_j U^\dagger={\bf s}^T \Omega G \hat{\bf r}$